# how to use relative layout inside the frame layout

Tags: android-layout

can i use relative layout inside the frame layout? in this the id=relative layout02 i want to use the option android:layout_below=relativelayout01 but that is not there so i am using android:layout_marginTop="100dip" but this is also not working....i want place this relaytivelayout02 below relative layout01...how it is possible? thanks for help....

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true" android:background="@drawable/mainscreen"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout00">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:text="@string/title" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="26sp" android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="96dip" android:layout_marginTop="100dip">
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/qutn" android:text="Question" android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:src="@drawable/transprent"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to my understanding to your question, I think you can place your both Layouts inside another(parent) Relative layout. So, you can place your 2nd Relative Layout BELOW your 1st Relative Layout.